# Dificuldade com socket.recv()

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estou com problemas de continuidade no meu código depois de uma chamada de função, relacionada ao recebimento de dados via socket com o seguinte código:

```
def le_dados(obj):

    lista_rcv = []
    while True:

        data = obj.recv(2)

        if data:
            lista_rcv.append(data)

            if len(lista_rcv) == 4:

                lista_rcv.append(obj.getpeername())
                global status_central
                status_central = lista_rcv
                lista_rcv = []

         sleep(0.25)
```

Essa função é chamada dentro de outra função assim:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=le_dados(s))
process.daemon = True    
process.start()
```

O que não estou conseguindo visualizar, talvez por falta de experiência é porque o código para na linha:

```
data = obj.recv(2)
```

Não deixando o o código seguir a diante na chamada do `process`,
fica parado aqui:

```
process = multiprocessing.Process(target=le_dados(s))
```

não deixando assim eu estartar minha Gui que vem depois disso.

Só complementando, segue o restante do código, ele é usado para se conectar a dispositivos onde enviarei e receberei comandos, com um só deu certo, mas quando tento com vários não estou conseguindo.

```
import socket
import os
import Gcomn
from time import sleep  
import multiprocessing

PORT = 7557

status_central = []
on_off_disp = []

def conecta_dispositivos():

    sql = 'select nome_disp, Ip_disp from dispositivos'
    dados_dis = Gcomn.le_dados(sql)
    global on_off_disp
    on_off_disp = []

    for i in range (len(dados_dis)):

        try:
            s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
            #s.settimeout(5)
            s.connect((dados_dis[i][1] ,7557))            

            if s:   
                print("Conectado a: ", s.getpeername())
                sleep (1.5)
                sendData()
                on_off_disp.append(1)

                print('vou chamar o process')
                process = multiprocessing.Process(target=recebe_dados(s))
                process.daemon = True
                process.start()
                print('depois do process')

        except socket.error:
            print ('Erro ao conectar em: ', dados_dis[i][0])
            on_off_disp.append(0)


def recebe_dados(obj):

    lista_rcv = []
    obj.setblocking(False)
    while True:
        data = obj.recv(2)
        if data:

            lista_rcv.append(data)

            if len(lista_rcv) == 4:
                lista_rcv.append(obj.getpeername())
                global status_central
                status_central = lista_rcv
                lista_rcv = []
        else:
            print('não recebi nada')        

        sleep(0.25)


def sendData(comando = 'A00000'):

    s.send(comando.encode('utf-8'))

conecta_dispositivos()
```

Comment: Provavelmente, a chamada `recv` está bloqueando a execução até que receba algum dado através do socket. Você pode setar a conexão para não bloquear o programa assim que criar o socket `obj` com [`obj.setblocking(False)`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/socket.html#socket.socket.setblocking), porém, precisará tratar o caso onde você chamou o `recv` e não recebeu nenhum dado

Comment: Obrigado pela resposta, fazendo isso, o programa pula e executa o resto, porém, o bloco que é chamado no process que é o le_dados(), não funciona.

Comment: Se você mudar o `socket` para não bloquear, precisará mudar também o seu algoritmo. Com o código que está na pergunta ("travando"), você tentou conectar no `socket` a partir de outro programa (ex: telnet) e enviar algum dado? Ele não desbloqueou?

Comment: Eu estou tentando me conectar com alguns dispositivos que trabalham em modo servidor, fiz um codigo que funciona com um só e envia e recebe comandos normalmente mas quando tento me conectar com varios aparece o problema. Fiz um laço for e pego uma lista do banco com os dispositivos cadastrados e tento me conectar com cada um. Talvez seja ai o problema. não sei como posto todo o codigo na mesma pergunta. só editando?

Comment: Sim. É só editar a pergunta e acrescentar todas essas informações e o código! :)

Answer (score 1):

Como a conexão será feita a vários servidores (dispositivos) de forma contínua, será necessário criar um *socket* para cada um dos  servidores.

A função `recv` pode ser configurada para funcionar nos modos: "bloquear" até receber algum dado, não bloquear ou bloquear após um *timeout*.

A configuração que você irá utilizar depende muito da forma como você quer que o programa funcione (algoritmo).

Como o seu código utiliza multiprocessamento, uma estratégia possível é criar um processo para cada cliente, movendo todo o código do *looping* `for i in range (len(dados_dis)):` para um novo processo e deixar a conexão configurada como "bloquear".

Cada processo irá abrir uma conexão (diferente) com um dispositivo e tratar os dados de forma independente.

---

Segue, apenas a título de exemplo, o seu código modificado com esta alteração:

```
import socket
import os
import Gcomn
from time import sleep
import multiprocessing

PORT = 7557

status_central = []
on_off_disp = []

# Acrescentei o parâmetro: s (socket)
def sendData(s, comando = 'A00000'):
    s.send(comando.encode('utf-8'))

# Recebe os dados de 1 dispositivo no modo "bloqueio"
def recebe_dados(obj):
    lista_rcv = []
    while True:
        # Aqui, a conexão pode ser do tipo "bloqueio"
        data = obj.recv(2)
        if data:
            lista_rcv.append(data)
            if len(lista_rcv) == 4:
                lista_rcv.append(obj.getpeername())
                global status_central
                status_central = lista_rcv
                lista_rcv = []
        else:
            print('não recebi nada')
        sleep(0.25)

# Abre a conexão e mantém a comunicação com 1 dispositivo
def disp_interno(d):
    try:
        s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET,socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        s.connect((d[1] ,7557))
        if s:
            print("Conectado a: ", s.getpeername())
            sleep (1.5)
            sendData(s)
            on_off_disp.append(1)
            recebe_dados(s)
    except socket.error:
        print ('Erro ao conectar em: ', dados_dis[i][0])
        on_off_disp.append(0)

# Cria um processo diferente para cada dispositivo
def conecta_dispositivos():
    sql = 'select nome_disp, Ip_disp from dispositivos'
    dados_dis = Gcomn.le_dados(sql)
    global on_off_disp
    on_off_disp = []

    for i in range(len(dados_dis)):
        print('vou chamar o process')
        # Alterado para criar o processo, chamando a função: disp_interno
        # Envia como parâmetro os dados da conexão
        process = multiprocessing.Process(target=disp_interno, args=(dados_dis[i],))
        process.daemon = True
        process.start()
        print('depois do process')

    # o join() aguarda a finalização dos processos
    for process in multiprocessing.active_children():
        process.join()


if __name__=="__main__":
    conecta_dispositivos()
```

**Observações:**

- Como o multiprocessamento é utilizado para comunicação com dispositivos (*IO*), talvez haja vantagem em utilizar [*Threads*](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/threading.html) ao invés de *Process*.
- O código dentro do(s) processo(s) atualiza variáveis globais (`status_central` e `on_off_disp`), portanto, talvez seja necessário verificar se haverá ou não problemas de [*race condition*](https://pt.wikipedia.org/wiki/Condi%C3%A7%C3%A3o_de_corrida).
- Caso ocorra um problema em uma das conexões (o dispositivo remoto feche a conexão, instabilidade na rede, etc.), o processo responsável por essa conexão irá "morrer" no looping `while True:` dentro da função `recebe_dados()`. Acredito que essa situação precise ser tratada também.

Comment: Gomiero, muito obrigado pela resposta foi de grande valia, pesquisando um pouco, passei a usar threads mesmo como você aconselhou, e boa parte ja está funcionando, e, estou ciente que ainda falta um tratamento mais apurado nesse modulo que é onde estou trabalhando agora.

Comment: @Rafa710: De nada! :)